# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'problem' -- not sure why

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
class Multiplier2:
    
    def __init__(self, problem):
        self.problem = problem
        self.tokens = ()
        self.operands = ()

    def IsNumeric(self, token):
        try:
            int(token)
            return True
        except:
            return False
        
    def  Calculate(self):
        self.tokens = (self.problem.split('()'),)
        for x in tokens:
            if self.IsNumeric(x):
                self.operands += x
        print(self.operands[0] * self.operands[1])
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = Multiplier2
    X.Calculate(input('Enter problem: '))
```

and the stacktrace:

```
Enter problem: (9)9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/eclipse-workspace/Calculator/prealgebraopenstax/prealgebra/chapter1_4part2.py", line 31, in <module>
    X.Calculate(input('Enter problem: '))
  File "/home/david/eclipse-workspace/Calculator/prealgebraopenstax/prealgebra/chapter1_4part2.py", line 22, in Calculate
    self.tokens = (self.problem.split('()'),)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'problem'
```

I'm sure there are other errors in the logic. I there are I don't want to know, I'm doing this to learn. Please can someone help me figure out why this is happening.

I just wrote another one that runs with the line `tokens = self._problem.split('*')` - it runs fine
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please update your knowledge of classes, instances and methods.

Comment: `X = Multiplier2` -> `X = Multiplier2( some problem )`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: The code you supplied is not valid. There is no way to produce the same results. This must not be an up to date version of the code you are testing against.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Your proposed change is just as much a typo.

Comment: @quamrana. Yes. I updated my comment

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm pretty sure the issue is that the OP is trying to split on multiple characters using `str.split`. They should be using a regex for that.

Comment: @flakes. I'm pretty sure OP didn't get that far as is using SO as a code review service

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, there are a number of issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    X = Multiplier2(input('Enter problem: '))
    X.Calculate()
```

Previously you had set `X` equal to the class itself, rather than an instance of the class.

Comment: oops, just a typo more or less, didn't even think it might be in the test code. Thanks all!